# Custom QuerySet for a Django admin action

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

```
# Customers model

Customers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    emails = ArrayField(models.EmailField(), default=list, blank=True)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I have a QuerySet which has all the information according to the model of all the selected customers.

```
# Django admin action

    def get_email_ids(self, request, queryset):
        """
        QuerySet here is all the information according to the model of all the selected customers.
        """
        # new_queryset = ?
        return generate_csv(
            request,
            queryset,
            filename="email-ids.csv",
        )
```

I want a new custom QuerySet that only has the customer name and email id's. But it should be in the following way. If a customer has 10 email id's then there should be 10 rows for that customer in the QuerySet.

```
e.g.

customer1 email1@email.com
customer1 email2@email.com
customer1 email3@email.com
customer1 email4@email.com
customer2 emailother@email.com
```

How to achieve this for `new_queryset`?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how you could iterate through your arrayField emails in your queryset. For me the best you could do i to use .values("name","emails") and use for loop on emails...

Comment: A queryset is just a list of Django Model Objects, is that what you want? Or do you need a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following way to get the desired data.

```
Customers.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        .annotate(
            emails =Func(F("emails"), function="unnest")
        )
        .values(
            "name",
            "emails",
        )
        .distinct()
```